# AS3 - Instantiating classes inside Vectors

Tags: actionscript-3, class, vector

I am trying to to figure out how Vectors work with classes.
Well, I have this in my properties:

```
private var rockets:Vector.<Rocket> = new Vector.<Rocket>();
private var rocket:Rocket;
```

Rocket class is just a normal MovieClip class with an embedded image inside.

Now I have this code:

```
if (_pressingSpace)
{
    rocket = new Rocket(); 
    rocket.x = Random; 
    addChild(rocket); 
    rockets.push(rocket);
}
```

When you press space a rocket is created at a random x, instantiate the class Rocket and saves it to the var rocket. an addChild will display the image. Well, when you press space again from what I understand it does it all over again but replaces the data that were inside the var rocket with the current data(which has a new random x).
Well, this line saves every rocket to the class Vector:

```
rockets.push(rocket);
```

Now here's what I found in my testing: I created multiple rockets with space, then pressed x to show me the x's

```
if (_pressingX)
        {
            trace(rockets[0].x);
            trace(rockets[1].x);
            trace(rockets[2].x);
            trace(rockets);
            trace(rocket);
        }
```

And I did get all of the random x's, including all the rockets that were inside the vector. Well here's what I don't get: if every-time I press space I replace the data of the var rocket with the current one, how come I still can access it through "rockets"? Shouldn't it have disappeared with it? What exactly does it do, I need to know for my further work. btw when I do

```
trace(rocket.x);
```

All I can see is the recent rocket which I created, not the other ones.

Comment: Every time you do `new Rocket()` you create extra space in your RAM for that object, with its own address etc. Rather than putting the variable into the Array/Vector, you put its general information in it (at which address in the RAM can the object be found). If you wouldn't put those created Rockets into an array, they would be garbage collected after some time because they're not used anymore.

Comment: So why can't I trace all of them with a simple trace(rocket); I tried trace(rocket[1]); and it didn't work too. ? Also, how exactly does that information look, something like: coordinates, random name to differentiate etc?

Comment: Because you are overriding the variable. `private var rocket` is simply a placeholder that tells the compiler "when you create an object of this class, make enough space available in RAM to hold the information of this object". The information of the object are the variables and functions in it. So a Class that only has the variable `public var index:int` would keep 4 bytes available in the RAM (because integers are 4 bytes in AS3). A Vector/Array is kind of the same thing, but instead it can point to multiple objects instead of only one.

Comment: You cannot use `rocket[1]` because your Rocket class is not an Array or Vector (or in other words, it is not a list of objects, but a **single** object).

Answer (score 0):

A `var` is a finger. It points at you. Many fingers could be pointed at you, but there happens to be only one finger per `var`.

An `Array` is many fingers. It can be any amount of fingers (including 0 fingers). Every finger can point at anything (including nothing). Maybe the array is 1000 fingers pointing at you. Maybe one finger pointing at you and a second one pointing at me.

Your grandma is an `Array`. She points at all the family members (including you) with individual fingers.

Grandpa is a `var`. He points to the last born family member, which happens to be you in this example.

You form babby.

Grandpa now points his finger at `user2081462 Jr.` He does not point at you any more.

Question: Is still anybody pointing a finger at you?
Answer: Yes, grandma.

In other words: Deleting a picture of a person on your phone doesn't mean that all other picture(s) of that person existing on other phones or even the person itself is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesn't have anything to do with vectors. Replacing a reference does not replace all references to the same object -- references may be in vectors, arrays, object maps, or anything other variable. For example:

```
var a:Rocket = new Rocket();
var b:Rocket = a;
trace(a == b); // true; a and b refer to the same rocket
a = new Rocket();
trace(a == b); // false; a is a new rocket, b refers to the old rocket
```

There's no way to automatically remove all references to an object. You'll have to do it yourself. To remove elements from a vector you use [`splice()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html#splice()). For example, to remove an existing rocket from the vector:

```
var indexOfRocket:int = rockets.indexOf(rocket);
if(indexOfRocket > -1){
    rockets.splice(indexOfRocket, 1); // remove 1 element from index of rocket
}
```